# array_agg contains another array_agg

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, relational-division

```
t1
id|entity_type
9|3
9|4
9|5
2|3
2|5
           
t2  
id|entity_type
1|3
1|4
1|5
```

---

```
SELECT t1.id, array_agg(t1.entity_type)
    FROM t1
GROUP BY
    t1.id
HAVING ARRAY_AGG(t1.entity_type ORDER BY t1.entity_type) = 
    (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t2.entity_type ORDER BY t2.entity_type) 
        FROM t2
    WHERE t2.id = 1
    GROUP BY t2.id);
```

Result:

```
t1.id = 9|array_agg{3,4,5}
```

I have two tables `t1` and `t2`. I want to get value of `t1.id` where `t1.entity_type` array equals `t2.entity_type` array.

In this scenario everything works fine. For `t2.id = 1` I receive `t1.id = 9`.
Both have the same array of `entity_type`: `{3,4,5}`

Now I'd like to get `t1.id` not only for equal sets, but also for smaller sets.
If I modify `t2` this way:

```
t2  
id|entity_type
1|3
1|4
```

and modify query this way:

```
SELECT t1.id, array_agg(t1.entity_type)
    FROM t1
GROUP BY
    t1.id
HAVING ARRAY_AGG(t1.entity_type ORDER BY t1.entity_type) >= /*MODIFICATION*/
    (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t2.entity_type ORDER BY t2.entity_type) 
        FROM t2
    WHERE t2.id = 1
    GROUP BY t2.id);
```

I don't receive the expected result:

```
t1.id = 1 has {3, 4, 5}     
t2.id = 1 has {3, 4}
```

Arrays in `t1` that *contain* the array in `t2` should qualify. I expect to receive results as in first case but I get no rows.
Is there any method like: `ARRAY_AGG` contains another `ARRAY_AGG`?

Comment: That's not what `>=` does. I think you want `@>`. It's all explained in the docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-array.html

Comment: Is the combination of `(id, entity_type)` unique in both tables? Ideally, you should provide complete table definitions to clarify the details. And your version of Postgres, of course.

Answer (score 5):

#### Clean up

It would be inefficient to use two differing invocations of `array_agg()`. Use the same (`ORDER BY` in `SELECT` list and `HAVING` clause):

```sql
SELECT id, array_agg(entity_type ORDER BY entity_type) AS arr
FROM   t1
GROUP  BY 1
HAVING array_agg(entity_type ORDER BY entity_type) = (
   SELECT array_agg(entity_type ORDER BY entity_type)
   FROM   t2
   WHERE  id = 1
   -- GROUP  BY id   -- not needed
   );
```

[Syntax basics in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)

#### "contains" operator [**`@>`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b8622/19)

Like [Nick commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684), your **2nd query** would work with the "array contains" operator `@>`

```sql
SELECT id, array_agg(entity_type ORDER BY entity_type) AS arr
FROM   t1
GROUP  BY 1
HAVING array_agg(entity_type ORDER BY entity_type) @> (
   SELECT array_agg(entity_type ORDER BY entity_type)
   FROM   t2
   WHERE  id = 1
   );
```

But this is very inefficient for big tables.

### Faster query

The problem can be cast as a case of **relational division**. Depending on your table definition, there are more efficient techniques. We have gathered a whole arsenal under this related question:

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)

**Assuming** `(id, entity_type)` is unique in both tables, this should be **substantially faster** for big tables, especially because it can use an **index** on `t1` (as opposed to your original query):

```sql
SELECT t1.id
FROM   t2
JOIN   t1 USING (entity_type)
WHERE  t2.id = 1
GROUP  BY 1
HAVING count(*) = (SELECT count(*) FROM t2 WHERE id = 1);
```

You need two indexes:

First on `t2(id)`, typically covered by the primary key.
Second:

```
CREATE INDEX t1_foo_idx ON t1 (entity_type, id);
```

The added `id` column is optional to allow index-only scans. Sequence of columns is essential:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xI86K7qM)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b8622/19)</sub>